# C# define LET in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, templates, let

I have multiple LINQ queries that uses the same LET variables, I would like to predefine these somehow.

```
IQueryable<RouteQueryModel> query =
    (from b in db.routes
     let avg_rating = b.ratings.Any() ? 
         b.ratings.Select(r => r.rating1).Average() : 
         0
     let distance_to_first_from_me = b.coordinates.
         Select(c => c.position).
         FirstOrDefault().
         Distance(DbGeography.FromText(currentLocation, 4326))
     let distance_to_last_from_me = b.coordinates.
         OrderByDescending(c => c.sequence).
         Select(d => d.position).
         FirstOrDefault().
         Distance(DbGeography.FromText(currentLocation, 4326))
     let distance_to_from_me = distance_to_first_from_me < distance_to_last_from_me ? 
         distance_to_first_from_me : 
         distance_to_last_from_me
     where b.endpoints.Any(e => values.Any(t => t == e.town.town_id))
     select new RouteQueryModel 
     { 
         b = b, 
         distance_to_from_me = distance_to_from_me.Value, 
         avg_rating = avg_rating
     }
 );
```

I'm using those three distance_to LETs in 8 different queries, is there any way to make a template for those that i can use in my queries?

Comment: are these queries all happen from the same method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an easy way to [pre-compile LINQ Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx):

```
var distanceToFirstFromMe =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<Route, GeoCoordinates, Distance>((route, currentLocation) => {
        return route.coordinates
            .Select(c => c.position)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Distance(DbGeography.FromText(currentLocation, 4326));
    });
```

To use them in your query, you can simply call them:

```
IQueryable<RouteQueryModel> query =
    (from b in db.routes
     let avg_rating = b.ratings.Any() ? 
         b.ratings.Select(r => r.rating1).Average() : 0
     let distance_to_first_from_me = distanceToFirstFromMe(b, currentLocation)
     // ...
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea for me to pre-compile my whole query except for the WHERE-statement?

Comment: That's pretty much a matter of preference I guess. An approach I'd prefer would be extracting the query into a method and pass a predicate function: `RouteQuery(route => { return route.endpoints.Any(...); })`